# GCD Prevents Call-back Blocks Being Called?

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, block, grand-central-dispatch

I am very new to GCD, but I am trying to only call certain code after other actions have completed. Anyway, this means I am using code you see below:

```
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                [self getTitlesArrayForChannel:channelID completionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *results) {
                        //Nothing in this block called, when method inside dispatch_group
                        [resultsDict setObject:results forKey:kFeedElementTitle];
                        NSLog(@"Received title result");
                }];
            });
```

So I am calling a method with a call-back block giving me the results of that method. When I put it inside the `dispatch_group_async`block the call-back block doesn't ever get called. Why might this be?

Something else worth noting would be, I am getting a console message when running this:
`Storing duplicate dispatch for GTLQueryYouTube selector setPart:`

I have no idea what it really means and can't find any relatable examples online. Possible it has something to do with it?

Basically, I am trying to call two different methods with call-back blocks, giving me results, then once I have results from both, I want to call a final block giving me a dictionary of each of the results. But I bumped into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with Google API, the error is not caused by GCD. You probably called this method:

```
+ (void)setStoredDispatchForClass:(Class<GTLRuntimeCommon>)dispatchClass
                     selector:(SEL)sel
                  returnClass:(Class)returnClass
               containedClass:(Class)containedClass
                      jsonKey:(NSString *)jsonKey;
```

This method stores the dispatch details for a class and selector. If you call two times this method passing the same class and selector, this code will be executed:

```
NSDictionary *selDict = (NSDictionary *)CFDictionaryGetValue(classDict, sel);
    if (selDict == nil) {
      selDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 jsonKey, kJSONKey,
                 returnClass, kReturnClassKey, // can be nil (primitive types)
                 containedClass, kContainedClassKey, // may be nil
                 nil];
      CFDictionarySetValue(classDict, sel, selDict);
    } else {
      // we already have a dictionary for this selector on this class, which is
      // surprising
      GTL_DEBUG_LOG(@"Storing duplicate dispatch for %@ selector %@",
            dispatchClass, NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    }
  }
```

In the else the error gets printed. You may see the code here:

http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/Objects/GTLRuntimeCommon.m

Comment: Ahh interesting. I am using the YouTube API as it happens. What could a possible solution be though? Is it possible to have separate dispatch groups running to avoid this duplicate error? As I get this error and then the query I execute, its block is never called probably as a result of this.

Comment: Essentially, what I meant to ask is. Because of Googles implementation of GCD, can I not use it in conjunction with many of their methods due to how they have made use of it?

Comment: I think you can use it safely. The problem is about removing duplicate calls to this method which contain the same class/selector. With some debug you may notice where the duplicate call is made and remove it.

Comment: Hmm, I have had a poke around with a lot of luck. I understand you can only help so much without seeing whats going on, but presumably then this is a problem inside Google's code which would need to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

The Google API does not appear to be thread safe. I was having similar problems, then I adjusted my code to ensure all API method calls occur on the main thread. Problem disappeared.